# Include requested URI in error log

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to track down "memory size exhausted" errors, but it's proving very difficult for a number of reasons.

- The error happens at different places, there doesn't seem to be a consistent "this is where memory is being consumed" spot.
- There is no stack trace included when this error is logged.
- I don't know what file was requested, which might have helped narrow down the cause.

Due to the nature of the error, it's doesn't seem to be caught by my "catch-all" error handler (although I may have done it wrong)

I'm wondering if it's at least possible to include `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in the logged error?

Comment: The log entry should match up with an access log entry for your web server. If you have control over the server, a tool such as newrelic might be a good thing to install.

Comment: You have to be specific, is it a memory exhausted error, or an out of memory error? They mean different things in PHP. Try including the exact error message you got and state which version of PHP. It matters.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was doing the "catch-all" error handler wrong.

The following code helped solve my problem:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
    $e = error_get_last();
    if( $e) {
        $info = "various debug info"; // as necessary
        error_log("[".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."] - ".$info);
    }
});
```

This helped narrow down the problem.

For anyone curious, the problem I was having was the session garbage collection - due to server maintenance there were over half a million sessions to clean up, easily overflowing the memory due to buffered queries loading them into memory. This also explains why it seemed so random... because it was! GC is called on a probability. I resolved the underlying problem by disabling session GC on user requests and adding it to the "general cleanup" cron script I already had. I also added `LIMIT 1000` to the query to avoid runaway problems like this in future. Kind of chilling to think someone could have easily DDoS'd my website by creating an absolute ton of sessions and then just waiting 24 hours for them to expire...